# Font-style is not applying to font-style specific @font-face fallback

Tags: css, font-face

I have a webfont that has very different widths between normal and italic. As a fallback I'm implementing Arial with a size-adjust for each. For some reason the italic version does not show up italic.

Based on the output the second fallback clearly works, except for the font-style. Maybe I'm missing something?

When I remove the font-style declaration from the italic fallback it works, but the normal version inherits the same fallback. How do I get around this?

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'fallback';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local(Arial);
  size-adjust: 110%;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'fallback';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local(Arial);
  size-adjust: 125%;
}

div {
  display: flex;
}

p {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: fallback;
  font-style: normal;
  color: green;
}

p + p { 
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: fallback;
  font-style: italic;
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>Sweet sweet marzipan dolor sweet marzipan candy croissant orange biscuit sugar cream sweet marzipan lollipop apple sprinkles sprinkles cake ipsum. Croissant pastry biscuit pastry sweet cake cream jelly croissant muffin ipsum biscuit tiramisu jelly sweet ipsum sweet dolor vanilla ipsum.</p>
<p>Sweet sweet marzipan dolor sweet marzipan candy croissant orange biscuit sugar cream sweet marzipan lollipop apple sprinkles sprinkles cake ipsum. Croissant pastry biscuit pastry sweet cake cream jelly croissant muffin ipsum biscuit tiramisu jelly sweet ipsum sweet dolor vanilla ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@font-face src refers to a specific font resource. Therefore the italic version should reference to the arial italic font e.g. `src: local(Arial Italic)`

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'fallback';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local(Arial);
  size-adjust: 110%;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'fallback';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local(Arial Italic);   /* <-- THIS HERE */
  size-adjust: 125%;
}

div {
  display: flex;
}

p {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: fallback;
  font-style: normal;
  color: green;
}

p + p { 
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: fallback;
  font-style: italic;
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>Sweet sweet marzipan dolor sweet marzipan candy croissant orange biscuit sugar cream sweet marzipan lollipop apple sprinkles sprinkles cake ipsum. Croissant pastry biscuit pastry sweet cake cream jelly croissant muffin ipsum biscuit tiramisu jelly sweet ipsum sweet dolor vanilla ipsum.</p>
<p>Sweet sweet marzipan dolor sweet marzipan candy croissant orange biscuit sugar cream sweet marzipan lollipop apple sprinkles sprinkles cake ipsum. Croissant pastry biscuit pastry sweet cake cream jelly croissant muffin ipsum biscuit tiramisu jelly sweet ipsum sweet dolor vanilla ipsum.</p>
</div>
```